# R Error in ci_bod() "Data set not numeric at column: 1"

Tags: r, error-handling, economics

I am currently trying to use the `ci_bod()` from the package `Compind` in R to use the Benefit of the Doubt approach (BoD) for creating a composite indicator.
I have a data frame (called "Data" in this example) with 7 subindicators (all numeric) which I would like to use to compile a composite indicator, which looks like this:

```
  Indic1        Indic2       Indic3       Indic4      Indic5       Indic6    Indic7
1 0.1310393914 -0.0688025494 0.0893357652 0.000000000 4.603536e-03 2.1277933 2.697052e-01
2 0.0573747901 -0.0800260705 0.3375335011 0.160919540 1.437293e-01 3.1103126 0.000000e+00
3 0.3430466905 -0.3456877394 0.1686795550 0.136363636 1.267847e-01 1.4737773 4.872327e-01
```

When I run the code I get the following error:

```
CI = ci_bod (Data)
```

> Error in ci_bod(Data) : Data set not numeric at column: 1

I already ran the following codes to check:

```
is.numeric(Data$Indic1)
# [1] TRUE
typeof(Data$Indic1)
# [1] "double"
class(Data$Indic1)
# [1] "numeric"
```

I am thinking of also normalizing the indicators first before running the ci_bod, however I get the same error:

```
normalise_ci(Data,c(1:7),"POS", method=1, z.mean=0, z.std=1, ties.method ="average")
```

> Error in normalise_ci(Data,c(1:7), "POS", method = 1, z.mean = 0,  :
> Data set not numeric at column: 1

I am a bit confused as to why I am getting this error considering all the data is indeed numeric, and would really appreciate your help if you have any ideas in what could be causing this error.

Also to display the contents:

```
> str(Data)
tibble [3 × 7] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ Indic1: num [1:3] 0.131 0.0574 0.343 
 $ Indic2: num [1:3] -0.0688 -0.08 -0.3457 
 $ Indic3: num [1:3] 0.08934 0.33753 0.16868 
 $ Indic4: num [1:3] 0 0.1609 0.1364 0.0976 
 $ Indic5: num [1:3] 0.0046 0.1437 0.1268 
 $ Indic6: num [1:3] 2.128 3.11 1.474 
 $ Indic7: num [1:3] 0.269705 0 0.487233
```

Comment: Can you show the `str(Data)`.  I tried this by copying your data, it is working without an error i.e. `> CI2 <- ci_bod(Data);
> CI2#
$ci_bod_est
[1] 1 1 1...`

Comment: Hi @akrun Thanks a lot for your time. I already edited the text to show the str(Data). I was just able to solve the error now by saving the data as a matrix instead Data1 <- data.matrix(Data, rownames.force = NA). Now the code works for me too. Weird since the examples for ci_bod show that a data.frame can be used.